# ReferenceError: Velocity is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, velocity, velocity.js

Looking for a resolution for this issue. I set up velocity on wordpress and seem to have run into a wall. When I reference velocity, I get Velocity not defined, and when I reference $.Velocity, I get $ not defined. Jquery 1.11.3 and Velocity are installed but the script that I am running on velocity does not call any Jquery items.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
// Velocity.js instead of CSS for performance
var city = document.querySelector('.js-city-1');
var fulllogo = document.querySelector('.cityanimation');
var loading = [animatecity()];

function animatecity() {
    // Reset
    Velocity(city, {
        'stroke-dasharray': 3542,
        'stroke-dashoffset': 3542
    }, 0);
    // Animate
    Velocity(city, {
        'stroke-dashoffset': 0
    }, {
        duration: 20000,
        complete: function() {
            Velocity(city, {
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                duration: 500
            }), animatefulllogo();
        }

        ,
    });
}

function animatefulllogo() {
    // Reset
    Velocity(fulllogo, {
        opacity: 1
    }, 0);

    // Animate
    Velocity(fulllogo, {
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        complete: function() {;
        }
    });
};



Velocity.RunSequence(loading);
```

```css
#loadscreen{
 z-index: 9999;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

#loaderimage{
 background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/silicon-city/images/SiliconCity.jpg);
 background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: 100%;
 -ms-background-size: 100%;
 background-size: 100%;
 max-width:1035px;
 min-width:360px;
 position: fixed;
}

#Layer_1{
 margin-top:8px;
}

.cityanimation {
 background-color: #FFF;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 width:75%;
 max-width:1035px;
 min-width:360px;
 position: fixed;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari */
}

.st0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:#28B24B;
 stroke-width:.15em;
 stroke-linecap:round;
 stroke-linejoin:round;
 stroke-miterlimit:10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>

<div id="loadscreen">
<div id="loaderimage">
<div class="cityanimation">
     <object>
          <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink=   "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1035 393" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1035 393;" xml:space="preserve">

<path class="st0 js-city-1" d="M1.521,213.364h59.398l6.658-0.488v-57.018h15.737v-6.528l10.905-0.134v5.685h17.706l0.122,3.899h1.178h7.636
 v23.01l6.009,0.057v-3.574h5.524v4.145h12.426l0.082-4.956h6.822v2.597h5.685V139.75h4.009v-8.015h1.649v-4.713h1.415v-4.716h1.18
 v-6.363h1.649v6.363h0.942v4.244h1.887v5.422h11.551v3.065l13.673,13.674v28.289l16.138-0.351v-24.526h2.438v-7.961h32.489v25.018
 h4.873v-23.396h13.646v12.35h19.492v18.191h3.574v11.35l16.245,0.027v-35.578h29.727v11.914h10.942l0.268-34.333h19.33v28.102h9.746
 l1.625,37.933h8.937v-17.652l42.396-1.598V158.78h13.807l2.763-112.293h2.436v-3.899h5.684v-8.936h-1.136v-2.437h1.623V2.139
 L453.054,1l0.49,0.976v29.239h1.786v2.437h-1.299v8.771h5.847v3.899h2.926l2.422,136.264h8.765l0.183-10.971h4.063v-2.762
 c0,0,7.389-6.746,13.97,0l1.625-6.498l8.284-5.847l7.637,5.197l2.596,5.196h4.225v-8.932h18.844v23.555h9.096v15.568l23.398-0.359
 v-24.518h5.463v-5.809h6.764v-25.592h24.609v36.268h27.301v-17.017h9.902v-7.386h9.695v3.806h16.051v3.136h13.098v3.806h3.158
 v-14.778h4.408l1.732-19.33l2.691,19.371h3.584v18.543h4.215v5.15h10.146v14.332h7.527v-12.093h2.74V141.26h2.951v-5.151h12.334
 v36.05h3.795v22.393h5.609v-17.914h8.773l2.316-0.006v24.859h14.514h2.529v-15.662h3.939v-13.444h3.775V88.216h2.713v-6.998h4.416
 v-6.996h1.988c0.1-0.31,0.209-0.6,0.285-0.898c1.094-4.186,1.883-8.421,1.992-12.759c0.029-1.136,0.055-2.275-0.025-3.406
 c-0.072-0.959,0.209-1.709,0.934-2.299c0.225-0.181,0.289-0.365,0.289-0.636c-0.008-4.522,0.037-9.042-0.027-13.56l0.049-0.999
 c-0.016,4.854-0.006,9.711-0.014,14.57c0,0.299,0.035,0.49,0.367,0.642c0.652,0.3,1.113,0.844,1.24,1.553
 c0.086,0.497,0,1.021,0.004,1.533c0.006,1.682-0.076,3.372,0.059,5.042c0.162,1.95,0.451,3.896,0.809,5.823
 c0.336,1.814,0.828,3.597,1.25,5.394c0.055,0.239,0.174,0.334,0.436,0.324c0.541-0.024,1.086-0.007,1.674-0.007v7.019h4.143v6.982
 h2.924v84.164h3.479v8.4h4.441l4.865,0.002v-16.695v-12.764h7.533v-3.808h13.012v-9.853h5.395v15.004h9.057v-18.136h17.057v10.075
 h12.141v-4.702h4.238v4.477h5.395v-8.507h10.02v9.18h4.049v19.928h7.23v7.611h7.6v-17.018h1.732v-3.58h10.404v43.213h10.994v-86.428
 h2.311v-3.357h2.699v-3.582h16.752v4.029h2.508v3.583h1.926v83.945h5.852l-0.031-56.667l0.678-5.362l-1.469-0.789l0.057-0.396h1.525
 l0.111-16.925l0.336-1.243l1.297-0.395l0.287-3.723l0.732-1.581c-0.074-1.429-0.574-2.858,0.619-4.289
 c0.26-1.902-0.264-4.195,1.355-5.417c0.27-2.018-0.154-4.479,1.639-5.528c0.332-1.789-0.354-3.573,1.07-5.36
 c0.236-2.353,0.145-4.705,1.072-7.053l0.336-5.304l0.283-19.241l0.678,18.279l0.678,6.827c0.838,2.051,0.635,4.103,0.789,6.151
 c1.395,1.619,0.92,3.236,0.902,4.855c2.518,1.938,1.785,4.069,1.92,6.149c1.561,0.804,1.262,3.283,1.41,5.36
 c1.109,1.447,0.959,2.898,0.902,4.344c0.451,1.581,0.695,3.16,0.848,4.74l1.352,1.129l0.451,5.076l0.115,13.262l0.676,0.563
 l0.678-0.506l0.395,0.111l-0.057,0.508l-1.354,0.677v5.643l0.508,0.339l0.557,50.658h8.58v-11.014h19.199l-0.006,0.919v34.813
 l7.383,1.607l-14.375,0.805l14.375,2.41l-15.15,1.205l15.924,2.412l-14.76,1.607l6.604,1.205v57.908h-15.236h-8.654h-33.711"/>
</svg>

     </object>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I also tried the following... thought it might be worth a shot..

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {


// Velocity.min.js instead of CSS for performance
var $city = $(".js-city"),
    $fulllogo = $(".cityanimation");
var loading = [animatecity()];

function animatecity() {
    // Reset
    $city
    .velocity({
        'stroke-dasharray': 3542,
        'stroke-dashoffset': 3542
    }, 0);
    // Animate
    $city
    .velocity({
        'stroke-dashoffset': 0
    }, {
        duration: 20000,
        complete: function() {
            $city
            .velocity({
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                duration: 500
            }), animatefulllogo();
        }

        ,
    });
}

function animatefulllogo() {
    // Reset
    $fulllogo
    .velocity({
        opacity: 1
    }, 0);

    // Animate
    $fulllogo
    .velocity({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        complete: function() {;
        }
    });
};


animatecity();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Okay... ended up with this.. but looks like Velocity.js doesn't load on window. I did confirm to see if Velocity.js was in the correct directory and it is. The animation still does not work but I am not getting any errors..

```js
(function($) {


// Velocity.min.js instead of CSS for performance
var city = document.querySelector('.js-city');
var fulllogo = document.querySelector('.cityanimation');

function animatecity() {
    // Reset
    $.Velocity(city, {
        'stroke-dasharray': 3542,
        'stroke-dashoffset': 3542
    }, 0);
    // Animate
    $.Velocity(city, {
        'stroke-dashoffset': 0
    }, {
        duration: 20000,
        complete: function() {
            $.Velocity(city, {
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                duration: 500
            }), animatefulllogo();
        }

        ,
    });
}

function animatefulllogo() {
    // Reset
    $.Velocity(fulllogo, {
        opacity: 1
    }, 0);

    // Animate
    $.Velocity(fulllogo, {
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        complete: function() {;
        }
    });
};


animatecity();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ok so I tried declaring jquery before velocity and it did not function. I then went ahead and attempted a noconflict, which didnt work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare jquery before velocity in your markup scripts

You can see velocity dependence package depends on jquery 1.4 version or more, so it is being dependent on jquery for something.

The reason is that word press actually defines jQuery as jQuery not $. If you run this code:

```
jquery(document).ready(function () {
  var $ = jQuery;
  console.log('Now jquery is $', $);
});
```

**So you should have source code jQuery and then asign to $ and finally source code of velocity.**

Comment: weird, when I use velocity.js independently it works. I mocked it up without jquery and it worked just fine =(

Comment: you are right you should not have this problem as it is a dependence on jquery from velocity it should be resolved with npm, I am trying a codepen with your case and i can see it works without jquery

Comment: After doing some research looks like wordpress actually defines jquery not as $ but as jQuery.

Comment: So what you could do is actually call document ready with parameter jQuery, and the argument call it $ so velocity should be defined as $ too, or work around to make velocity get jQuery as $ not as jQuery variable.

Comment: Hah! As soon as I run that.. I get ReferenceError: jquery is not defined.. not my day I suppose.

Comment: One more shoot look at this reference in order to see if it could be a bad reference to jquery:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: References look good, I must've checked it out at least 15 times. No luck =(